laravel pusher не работает почему то отправка
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST') ?: 'api-'.env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1').'.pusher.com',
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 443),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],

Файл конфигурации не трогал просто добавлял в env креды ,на прямую креды работают если использовать
public function sendTestMessage()
    {
        $options = [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'useTLS' => true
        ];
        $pusher = new Pusher(
            env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            $options
        );

        $data['message'] = 'hello world';
        $pusher->trigger('test-channel', 'my-event', $data);

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Event has been sent!']);
    }

Отправляю Event после того как создал заказ но сам event не приходит в pusher Debug Console
Использую laravel 11

пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Спасибо , изменил фото на текст

Начал отвечать и устал), много что тут не видно. broadcast и вебсокет как настроен? Видно что конфигурация правильная и почему так каналы создаются? Ещё  не понятно как окружение настроено.
Вот нашёл полезное видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmlGQagOmck
Всё по полочкам раскладывает...

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.

Cпасибо большое , помогло
